# How to extract the words which have both alphabetical and numerical characters?

Tags: php, regex

I want to extract the words which have both alphabetical and numerical characters/
for example the function returns ac64fc in text below:
foo ac64fc bar 4544

```
 preg_match('/^[0-9A-Z]*([0-9][A-Z]|[A-Z][0-9])[0-9A-Z]*$/', $subject);
```

I wrote this regulareexpression to find if there is any 
but I don't know how can I extract the word (ac64fc )

Comment: So for clarification, you want to match the full *words* that contain **both** an alphabetic character **and** a numerical character? E.g. match `ac64fc`, but not `foo` or `4544`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are forcing input string to be only in the given format by `^` and `$` anchors. Replace them with `\b` (word boundary token) **and you are done** (also don't forget to enable `i` flag which makes it case-insensitive).

Also to simplify, you could use the following version which obviously doesn't invoke lookarounds:

```
\b(?:[a-z]+\d|\d+[a-z])[a-z\d]*\b
```

See [live demo here](https://regex101.com/r/qAa8JL/1)

PHP code:

```
preg_match('/\b(?:[a-z]+\d|\d+[a-z])[a-z\d]*\b/i', $subject);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are no uppercase characters in your string, but you might use a word boundary `\b` and a  positive lookahead `(?=` to assert a digit and when matching make sure to match at least one character a-zA-Z.

(Or the other ways around, looking for a character a-z and match at least 1 digit)

```
\b(?=[A-Za-z0-9]*[0-9])[A-Za-z0-9]*[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*\b
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/c62U1o/1)

Using the case insensitive flag, you code might look like:

```
$subject = "foo ac64fc bar 4544";
preg_match('/\b(?=[A-Za-z0-9]*[0-9])[A-Za-z0-9]*[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*\b/i', $subject, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]); // ac64fc
```

Comment: @ZaGol Did you try it like this? https://3v4l.org/968VD What is the data that you used?

Comment: :How can i convert the $matches[0] from array to a text ? i have yo pass it to a method which get a text variable , when i send $matches[0], it shows nothing and when i ssend $matches it shows `Array`

Comment: @ZaGol Can you share the code or send a link which shows the code and the data that you used?

Comment: `preg_match('/\b(?=[A-Za-z0-9]*[0-9])[A-Za-z0-9]*[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*\b/i', $subject, $matches);
message($chat_id,$matches,$message_id); ` -> shows Array
`message($chat_id,$matches[0],$message_id);` -> shows nothing

Comment: @ZaGol Are you sure you have the right data? https://3v4l.org/YckNJ What does `var_dump($subject):` give you?

Comment: yes , the message method has no problem and works properly when i send string to it , like :  `message($chat_id,'tttttt',$message_id);` shows -> tttttt
but `message($chat_id,var_dump($matches),$message_id)` shows nothing

Comment: Did you try `($chat_id,$matches[0],$message_id);`

Comment: yes, in the fourth comment i mentioned that it returns nothing

Comment: I think you should first check what the outcome is of `var_dump($subject);` to check if you are using the expected data.

Comment: I changed it to message($chat_id,var_dump($matches[0][0]),$message_id)  and it returns only the first charachter of the word (letter a in this example, instead of ac64fc)

Comment: I think that is because `$matches[0]` contains `ac64fc` and `$matches[0][0]` will give you the first character `a` but you should not pass `var_dump($matches[0][0])` as an argument, you should pass only `$matches[0]` as an argument.  That is why you first need to run `var_dump($subject);` as a separate command to see what it contains and make sure that it is the string `"foo ac64fc bar 4544"`

Comment: yes you are right , sorry i copied the code wrongly, it doesnt have `var_dump` and as you said $matches[0] returns the word, i changed the regular expresion to what @revo said in second post and it worked `\b(?:[a-z]+\d|\d+[a-z])[a-z\d]*\b` thank u for your help

Answer (score 1):

Try Regex: `(?=\w*\d)(?=\w*[a-zA-Z])[A-Za-z\d]+`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cRAu9c/1)